# Optimally get ancestor relation id from anywhere in the database tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails application with PostgreSQL where user roles are based on what project are assigned to.

`Project` has a hierarchical tree of tables under it.

I would like to know if there is an optimal way to get the `project_id` from anywhere in the tree.

So far my approaches have been:

1. Adding(chaching) a `project_id` column on every second node, and always adding a `belongs_to :project, through:...` option in models so I can always find it by directly calling `project.id` on any object. - Doesn't seem like the most reasonable option since most of the data don't have anything direct with `project`
2. Using `JOIN` and joining tables manually from every level of the tree to find `project_id` - very dirty approach since I have to manually map every level of the tree to the parent `project_id`

Are there any better ways to do this? Since this is related to permissions, these will be awfully frequent queries, so they have to be fast enough...

Comment: Providing the schema would be good, because it isn't clear to me if you really have many tables or if you have an adjacency list (in which case you could simple use a `WITH RECURSIVE` query)

Comment: Providing schema is hard, since it is not fully developed yet. But the requested specification show pretty clearly that the relationships would be around 5-6 levels deep + related amongst them as well.